# How to process light text with dark background with TextCleaner

Tags: imagemagick, ocr

As the title specifies, most images that I collect have dark background and light words, which makes tesseract difficult to identify the embedded texts. Anyone knows how I can swap two colors with TextCleaner? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no flag for that in my textcleaner script. But I will try to add one. Right now you can do it by piping a -negate ImageMagick command into the script:

```
convert input -negate miff:- | textcleaner -f 20 -o 10 - output
```

EDIT: I have just posted another version of the script to permit one or two way inversion. So the example above would be

```
textcleaner -f 20 -o 10 -i 1 input output
```

where -i 1 means to invert the colors of the input. If you want to invert the colors, then process and then invert back again for the output, then use -i 2.

Note that if you are using textcleaner for commercial use, then please contact me about licensing it.

Comment: My case is for research use. Thank you, Fred! It works:-)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider up-voting it.